# how to get keys of nested object

Tags: javascript, react-native

If I have a flat object then this works:

```
 let stateCopy={...this.state}

 Object.entries(dictionary).map(([key,value])=>{
 stateCopy.key = value.toString())
 })
```

Is there a way to do this if dictionary contains a nested object.  Suppose a dictionary looks like:

```
dictionary={left:{name:'WORK',
                  min:2,
                  sec:0,}
            start:true}
```

I need some way of updating stateCopy, i.e

```
stateCopy.left.name='WORK' 
stateCopy.left.min=2 
stateCopy.left.sec=0 
stateCopy.start=true
```

Comment: Could you give an example of state and a result you'd like?  Also, I think this is really a more general JS question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function flattenDictionary(dict) {
  if (!dict) {
    return {};
  }

  /** This will hold the flattened keys/values */
  const keys = {};

  // Perform the flatten
  flattenH(dict);

  return keys;

  function flattenH(obj, prefix) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
      const val = obj[key];

      /** This is what we pass forward as a new prefix, or is the flattened key */
      let passKey;
      // Only expect to see this when the original dictionary is passed as `obj`
      if (!prefix || prefix === '') {
        passKey = key;
      } else {
        // "Ignore" keys that are empty strings 
        passKey = ((key === '') ? prefix : `${prefix}.${key}`);
      }

      if (typeof obj[key] !== 'object') {
        keys[passKey] = val;
      } else {
        flattenH(val, passKey);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: this is similar to doing a deep copy

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can do this with a little recursive function:

```js
let state = {
    left:{
        start: "mark",
        anotherLevel: {
            test: 'leveltest'
        }
    },
    test: "will be replaced"
}
let dictionary={
    test2: {
      foo: 'bar'  
    },
    left:{
        name:'WORK',
        min:2,
        sec:0,
        anotherLevel: {
            test_add: 'leveltest_add'
        }
    },
    start:true,
    test: 'replaced with me'
}

let  stateCopy={...state}

function merge(obj, dict){
    Object.entries(dict).forEach(([k, v]) =>{
        if (!obj[k] || typeof v !== 'object')  obj[k] = v
        else  merge(obj[k], v)
    })
}
merge(stateCopy, dictionary)
console.log(stateCopy)
```